# Showing elements below overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's deal, I have `div`s that placed below `overflow: hidden` and need somehow manage to show them.

```css
.body {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 560px;
  height: 500px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100px;
}

.sidebar-container_hidden-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-element {
  width: 250px;
  height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.sidebar-element__linked-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(250px + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-container_hidden-scroll">

      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

After Adding `parent:: overflow: hidden, children:: overflow: scroll`

```css
.body {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 560px;
  height: 500px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar-container_hidden-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-element {
  width: 250px;
  height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.sidebar-element__linked-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(250px + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-container_hidden-scroll">

      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

The reason that I added those lines it's to scroll content and hide scroll bar. My goal here is to make "scrollable" content, hide scrollbar and still be able to see dotted rectangles. How can I do this? (`z-index` didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to position one of them as absolute in my opinion.
If you already using `flex` with the parent, then you can use `flex-direction:reverse` to make the `.main-container` stick to the right.

```css
.body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 560px;
  height: 500px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.sidebar-container_hidden-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-element {
  width: 250px;
  height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.sidebar-element__linked-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(250px + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-container_hidden-scroll">

      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element">
        <div class="sidebar-element__linked-div"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-element__name">
          Yellow flower
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-element__capacity">
          10 kg
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="main-container">

  </div>
</div>
```